# How do I create a Chrome Extension to change a message (inner HTML) on the Twitter homepage (DOM)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am trying to create a Chrome extension that changes the "What's on your mind?" message in the Twitter status update box, but I am stuck.

Here is my manifest:

```
{
"name":"Change Status Update",
"description":"Changes the What's On Your Mind Message",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://twitter.com/*"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "js": ["myscript.js"],
        "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
"permissions": [
    "activeTab"
]
}
```

And here is my content script (myscript.js) file is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("public-DraftEditorPlaceholder-inner").item(0).innerText = "Are you sure you want to post that?"
```

As you can see, it is a pretty simple extension.

Now, my problem is the content script works perfectly to change the Twitter status update message when I run it directly within the developer tools console in Chrome, but not when I run it within a content script in the Chrome extension.

In this case, I continuously get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of undefined."

Does anyone have any insight into this? I can't find any similar info from other stack overflow questions. Thank you!

Comment: The element doesn't exist when your script runs. You'll have to wait until Twitter has finished building the page.

Comment: That's why I said "run_at": "document_end." Should I say something else?

Comment: That waits until the HTML page is loaded, but Twitter then generates the rest of the page dynamically with JavaScript. Unfortunately there's no simple hook for when that's done.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Is there a workaround (i.e., waiting a few seconds after the page loads, or something like that?)